# How to integrate $\frac{1}{3+\sin x+\cos x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I can easily do it with $\tan {\frac{x}{2}}$ substitution, but my problem requires $x\in(0,2\pi)$.

$\int \frac{1}{3+\sin x+\cos x}dx, x\in(0,2\pi)$

How do i solve it now ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'requires $x\in(0,2\pi)$'?

Comment: What is the difficulty caused by the bounds, exactly? Just split it into two integrals over $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi)$, should work just fine

Comment: @EeveeTrainer can i do this with indefinite integrals also?

Comment: @PNDas that is the domain of my function

Comment: $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \sin(x) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \cos(x) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right) = \sqrt{2} \cos( x - \frac{\pi}{4})$. This could help.

Comment: My engine finds the solution $\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sin(x)/\sqrt{7}}{1 + \cos x}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)$

Comment: If you can do it with the $\tan(x/2)$ substitution, you can take the formal result, if it is defined in $[0, 2\pi]$ and differentiate it as a proof.

Comment: @Gribouillis when i use $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ substitution i get $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ in the final answer as well so it is not defined. Can some manipulations make it defined?

Comment: Add the result that you found in the question. It can certainly be transformed as my formal engine found a solution where there is no $\tan(x/2)$. Note that in this solution, there is a problem when $x=\pi$ but it can be transformed by using $\tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(1/x)= \text{sgn}(x) \pi/2$

Comment: @Gribouillis i found your solution as well when I input my integral here [link](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) in the computed by maxima field. $\frac {2}{\sqrt 7} * \arctan \frac {2 * \tan \frac{x}{2} + 1}{\sqrt 7}$ is the solution i found and it corresponds with the manual field on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the substitution $x=\pi + y$ with $y\in (-\pi, +\pi)$. The integral becomes
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d y}{3 - \sin(y)-\cos(y)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(
\frac{4\tan\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) - 1}{\sqrt{7}}\right) + C
\end{equation}
after integration with the $\tan(y/2)$ substitution. Now replace $y$ with $x-\pi$ and the solution is defined in $(0, 2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\sin x=2t/(1+t^2), \cos x=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2), tan(x/2)=t \implies 2 \sec^2(x/2) dx=dt$. Then
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{3+\sin x+ \cos x}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{dt}{t^2+t+2}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{dt}{(t+1/2)^2+7/4}==\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}} \tan^{-1} \frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{7}}+C.$$
where $t=\tan(x/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Making the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ gives \begin{align}I(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1+t^2}{2+t+t^2}\frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt=\int\frac{1}{2+t+t^2}\,dt=\frac{4}{7}\int\frac{1}{1+(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt7})^2}\,dt\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt7}\arctan(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt7})=\frac{2}{\sqrt7}\arctan(\frac{2\tan(x/2)+1}{\sqrt7})\end{align}

The problem with this is that this substitution is only valid for $0\le x<\pi$. In fact, at $x=\pi^+$, the above formula become negative, but there's nothing amiss in the original integrand at $x=\pi$.

For $x>\pi$, one needs to add a constant to keep the integral continuous, namely $$I(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt7}\arctan(\frac{2\tan(x/2)+1}{\sqrt7})+\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt7}$$